# What are the records that can be used in India to trace one's ancestry?

Tags: family-tree, locating-records, india, family-register

I'm an Indian and all my ancestors as far as I know are from India. I'm actually trying to reconstruct my family tree by tracing it back. The resources within family like various documents, certificates and stuff helped me to reach only as far as early 1900s. What other public records/documents I should be scouting next to go beyond that?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  While awaiting answers to your question you may like to review some previous questions here that have been tagged [tag:india].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent resource for you to look at next, assuming that you have not already, is the [India research page of FamilySearch.org](https://familysearch.org/search/collection/location/1927063) which enables you to immediately start searching for your ancestors.

From there you can link off into the [FamilySearch Wiki for India](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/India) which provides an excellent overview to a selection of the various family history resources which are available for India.

I recommend working with those to see where they lead, which I think will inevitably be to more focussed questions about specific ancestors which this site excels at providing answers to.

For advice that is more general but applies to India or anywhere in the world I recommend a Q&A that currently tops our [FAQ](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent):

- [Determining what records are available in a particular locale?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/how-can-i-determine-what-records-are-available-in-a-particular-locale)