# Where to find ship manifests for immigrants to Venezuela, 1946-1953?

Tags: 20th-century, immigration, locating-records, latvia, venezuela

I'm researching Latvian immigrants after WWII to Venezuela.

Where can I find ship manifests for immigrants to Venezuela during the period 1946-1953?

Comment: Welcome to FH&G.SE!  While you are waiting for an answer, our question [Q: How can I determine what records are available in a particular locale?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/how-can-i-determine-what-records-are-available-in-a-particular-locale) has some answers about how to find out what records might exist for Venezuela.

Comment: Arturo, do you know their European departure port (approximately) and if they sailed directly to Venezuela or if they arrived in another country first then took another ship? Are you also Spanish speaking as I found a couple sites in Spanish that have some passenger lists?

Comment: If you are interested in looking for family members named Neumann in Latvia, I can probably help you. ----------
The above has been Google translated from: > si tienes interes en buscar familiares con nombre Neumann en Latvia,
> possiblemente te puedo ayudar.

Comment: @Karl Welcome to G&FH SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour].  Here you are trying to make a comment in the area reserved for direct answers to the original question.  Such posts are normally deleted but in this case I will convert it to a comment.  If you have a reputation of less than 50 then there are [other strategies](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3860) that you can use to try to achieve your desired outcome but increasing your reputation is the simplest way forward.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a Spanish Speaker and / or can tolerate Google Translate the following are a couple places I have found you can try.

One thing to keep in mind is they may not have traveled directly from Latvia to Venezuela and may have stopped at several ports and changed ships along their journey both in Europe, possibly North America, as well as in South America. So I would also check popular ports possibly on the way... especially Brazil [per this note on this article](http://latvianhistory.com/2013/07/09/latvians-in-the-western-exile-1944-1991/) and the United States [as there is an estimated 40,000 Latvians](http://www.everyculture.com/multi/Ha-La/Latvian-Americans.html) during this time period of 1949-1951 that came through the US cities of New York, Boston, Philadelphia, and Chicago.

To note, Latvian nor any of the Baltic states are not [listed as one of the popular nationality / ethnic immigration groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigration_to_Venezuela) to Venezuela during the time period.

FamilySearch has [immigration cards for this time period for Brazil](https://familysearch.org/search/collection/list/?page=1&recordType=Migration&region=SOUTH_AMERICA) if they came via one of those ports.

Resource Wise in addition to checking the American immigration sites like Ancestry.com / etc

This page [BarcoseinImmigration.com](http://www.barcoseinmigrantes.com/index.html) is focused on Italian Immigration to South America but has good resources on ships and ports in South America as well as some searchable lists for many of the countries on one page; but the site is a bit hard to navigate and sometimes just takes you to other sites.

There is also a page on the from [Spain to America website](http://www.genealogiahispana.com/emigrantes/de-espana-a-america-de-que-barcos-descendemos/) (in Spanish) that has a good collection and links for researching many South American countries but is a bit light on Venezuela.

The [EveryCulture](http://www.everyculture.com/multi/Ha-La/Latvian-Americans.html) link also referenced above has a lot of specific links also to assist generally in Latvian immigration from Europe; in particular those mentioning it.

- [IMHC](http://www.umn.edu/ihrc) at University of Minnesota.
- The [American Latvian Association](http://www.alausa.org/lv/) (in Latvian)

There is also the less common method, which I would not have too high of expectations, of writing the [Latvian embassy](https://embassy-finder.com/es/latvia_in_caracas_venezuela?page=4) in Caracas, Venezuela. If you do utilize this option I would recommend to be put in contact with a local cultural group vs. requesting specific genealogy / family history information as most embassies are not equipped to handle such requests.