# Black History ancestry

Tags: 20th-century, census-records

I am running into dead ends when it come to my husband's family search from the mid 1900"s and before.

Does anyone know good information on slave records or older black ancestry record keeping?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about the site. I think we will need much more information before we will be able to help. You mention your husband's family but can you tell us what country and state they were living in. Please review our privacy policy in the [help/on-topic] and take care not to mention identifying details about anybody born less than 100 years ago without taking considerable care.

Comment: If your husband's ancestors lived in the US this question may be of interest: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/7879/19

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE! We can help you much better if you can ask specific, focused questions about exactly what kind of problems you are having in your research.  If you are having problems in "the mid 1900s" you may also be having difficulties with 20th-century privacy restrictions on records which is not unique to African-American genealogy.  Please tell us more about what you have already been able to do and where you have looked for records already -- then we can make better suggestions.