# Looking for German Ancestors earlier than 1700s?

Tags: research-methods, germany, 17th-century

I am a beginner and have been using Ancestry.com but German records seem to come to a halt at the WWI.

What can be used to search further back?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  I've made this a duplicate of an earlier question that should give you a number of avenues to pursue.  In addition this FamilySearch page may be useful to you: https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Germany_Genealogy

Comment: Eric: There's a mis-match between the date in the title (1700) and the date implied in the question (1914). Please make clear the era you are asking about. Learning that you are a beginner is good, but a quick summary your language capabilities and scope of the research you've done would also help us in writing our responses.

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful: [How can I determine what records are available in a particular locale?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3625/1006)

Comment: Thank You PolyGeo I appreciate the redirecting me. Thank you BGWIEHLE for the constructive criticism; I will try to be more precise. And thank you Jan, I will read through this. Thanks again all.