# Online resources for Cuban genealogy?

Tags: 19th-century, 20th-century, cuba

Is there an online source of information that can be publicly accessed which contains Cuban genealogy data? I have searched around but have not been able to find any.

In my specific case I am trying to find information that dates back to before the 1930's for the region surrounding Sancti Spiritus (the city where my grandparents are from).

Comment: https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Cuban_Family_History_Resources

Comment: I've re-edited my answer to add a few more links (and will keep doing so as I find them).  As relations improve between Cuba and the US, it may eventually be easier for people to do research in Cuba and to share their results with others online.

Comment: @JanMurphy then I can just accept the answer, and we can all update it as we find sources. Thanks again!

Comment: If you do find good resources, please feel free to come back and  self-answer your question.  It's good to have a separate answer because people can see what progress you made since you wrote the question, and it's better for the site statistics to have more answers instead of everyone adding to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I'm beginning research in an area which is unfamiliar to me, I generally start with the Research Wiki at FamilySearch.org.

The main article is [Cuba Genealogy](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Cuba_Genealogy) -- for research strategies, see the [Cuba Quick Start Guide](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Cuba_Quick_Start_Guide), which says:

> Unfortunately for those with ancestors from Cuba, FamilySearch does
>   not have any microfilmed or digitized records for Cuba.

Their pages on Cuba are not very extensive, but there is an article [Cuba  websites](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Cuba_Websites), including [CubaGenWeb.org](http://www.cubagenweb.org/).  To see other articles such as [Cuban Family History Resources](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Cuban_Family_History_Resources) search for the wiki category [Cuba](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Category:Cuba).  Remember, the Research Wiki started out with contributions from FamilySearch and is added to by volunteers, so it pays to go through every article to glean every bit of information you can find.

Just like when you are searching for a person, if searching for the country fails, try broadening the search to see what is available for the region.

Another good place to look for resources are the big directory sites like Cyndi's List: [Caribbean / The West Indies » General Resources](http://www.cyndislist.com/caribbean/general/)

Some websites which may be of interest:

- RootsWeb has mailing lists [CUBA-L](http://lists.rootsweb.ancestry.com/index/intl/CUB/CUBA.html) and [WEST-INDIES-L](http://lists.rootsweb.ancestry.com/index/other/Miscellaneous/WEST-INDIES.html)
- [Caribbean Genealogy Research's page on Cuba](http://www.candoo.com/genresources/#CUBA) has the addresses of archives in Cuba and links to their websites.
- [Digital Library of the Carribean](http://cms.uflib.ufl.edu/lac/digitalcollections) at the University of Florida which includes [The Caribbean Newspaper Digital Library (CNDL)](http://dloc.com/cndl)

Where there is no big "one-stop shopping" site to get you started, it helps to get creative with searches. Look for records, yes - but also look for research guides and finding aids, like the [Overview of Hispanic Research](https://www.ancestry.com/wiki/index.php?title=Overview_of_Hispanic_Research) published in Ancestry's Research Wiki.  Read genealogical periodicals and blogs, and see what sources other researchers used while doing their research.  Don't just look for things which might mention your family members -- look for anyone researching in the same time and geographical area, and read their work carefully, giving special attention to the bibliographies in published genealogical periodicals.

Doing general research on a locality can also yield clues.  Don't limit yourself to genealogical sites and genealogy societies -- information from a historical society's website or periodical can help you correctly interpret the details in any historical record you can find.

Online Catalogs that might help:

- Family History Library: Place search results for [Cuba](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=326&query=%2Bplace%3ACuba)
- [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/)
- [ArchiveGrid](https://www.worldcat.org/)

Keep an open mind while searching, because just like people, historical records and material about a country can end up far away from where it was created.  The US National Archives has [Records of the Provisional Government of Cuba](http://www.archives.gov/research/guide-fed-records/groups/199.html).  Will there be material here which is of genealogical interest?  Maybe not -- but if you had someone who died of yellow fever during the period of the US Provisional Government, the statistical reports might be of interest to you.

Lisa Louise Cooke's presentations on using Google for Genealogy are quite good:

- [Proven Methodology for Using Google for Genealogy](https://www.rootstech.org/video2/4741690732001) (video from RootsTech 2016)
- [Proven Methodology for Using Google for Genealogy](https://www.rootstech.org/bc/content/pdfs/syllabus-2016/get-started/GS2345-F_Cooke-GS2345-F%20Proven%20Methodology%20for%20Using%20Google_COOKE.pdf?lang=eng) (syllabus from RootsTech 2016)

I found these results via searching Google in the USA, in English.  Spanish speakers may be able to find better information by switching to searching to [Google Cuba](https://www.google.com.cu/) and searching there.

Making a research plan with specific research questions is a great way to focus on what information you want to find and where you might be able to find it. For other ideas, see [How can I determine what records are available in a particular locale?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3625/1006)