# Finding ancestor who came to England probably around the 1930s

Tags: malta

My wife is searching her great grandfather (Thomas Salvatore) who came to England probably around the 1930s.
We know he married a Scottish woman.
We have no other information.

I know it's really vague but where do we go from here?.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  Do you have her grandparents' birth certificates?

Comment: You have a tag for Malta.  Does that mean you know he came from Malta?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your question could be improved by adding what information you would like to know about your wife's great-grandfather.  Many of us would say "I want everything I can find!" and that's great as a goal, but what specifically would you like to know first? In the meantime, these questions and answers might help:

https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12524/1006  and https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3625/1006 The 20th Century can be tricky for research, because you'll be running into the 'privacy hole'.  Also, let us know how you know what you know.