# How can I find immigration or emigration records for Indians that went to Kenya in the 1920s?

Tags: immigration, india, emigration, manife, kenya

I am trying to find out how I can trace any sort of records, like ship manifests, arrival records or departure records for Indians that went to Kenya in the early 1900s (around 1920).

Is there a central archives in India or the UK where these kinds of emigration records are kept? Or are there archives with this information in Kenya?

Comment: While you're waiting for answers, you might get some ideas from https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3625/1006 and  https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12524/1006. Think about what laws might have applied to your individuals, what jurisdictions existed at the time, whose subjects your passengers would have been, etc.  What reading have you done for context about the time period?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenya_Colony etc.

Comment: Also, you may want to keep an eye on what's happening with the British Library's website https://britishlibrary.typepad.co.uk/living-knowledge/2023/11/cyber-incident.html since they hold records of the India Office.