# Monumental Inscriptions - Churchyard of St Mary & St Chad in Brewood, Staffordshire

Tags: church-records, grave-marker, staffordshire

Is anyone aware of an online-accessable index/list of the MI's for this churchyard?

I cannot find such on the CD of Staffordshire MI's published by BMSGH ([Midland-Ancestors](https://midland-ancestors.shop/)) nor within the [Staffordshire Collection on FindMyPast](https://www.findmypast.com/articles/staffordshire-monumental-inscriptions-parish-list).

Answer (score 1):

For a big-picture approach to this question, see [Determining what records are available for a particular locale?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3625/1006)

This is a general procedure for finding Staffordshire records. New record collections come online all the time, so even if these suggestions yield no results today, they may yield an answer tomorrow, next week, next month, or next year.  Step zero on any record search is to start a log or journal entry or report to yourself about where you searched, how you searched, and what your results are, and to set up a calendar entry or 'tickler' to remind yourself to repeat the search later if the initial search fails.

I have not limited this answer to searching only for online records.  When searching, my main goal is to determine what records survive and what archives they are held in. Once I have knowledge of what records exist, it is much easier to set up a Google Alert or watch in other ways for news about that record set coming online. (For an example of a item that might be worth a Google Alert, see the "Also of Interest" section at the bottom of this answer.)

Try searching for both records and finding aids, and search all jurisdictions.  In addition to searching general search engines and GenealogySE for prior questions, here are some places you can try.

- The GENUKI Gazetteer (results for [Brewood, Staffordshire](https://www.genuki.org.uk/big/eng/STS/Brewood))
- any website for the Online Parish Clerk, if one exists for the parish
- any online databases and/or the shop for the local FHS (any new additions may show up there long before they make it to findmypast or pay sites)
- The FamilySearch Research Wiki: main article [Brewood, Staffordshire Genealogy](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Brewood,_Staffordshire_Genealogy) and the main "big blue button" article for Staffordshire [Online Genealogy Records](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Staffordshire,_England_Online_Genealogy_Records)
- [Cemetery, Burial Ground & Crematoria Records](https://www.genguide.co.uk/source/cemetery-burial-ground-crematoria-records/) article at GenGuide
- place searches in the [FamilySearch Catalog](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog)
- [Staffordshire Genealogy](http://www.ukisearch.com/staffordshire.html) at UKISearch.com
- [Staffordshire Monumental Inscriptions links](https://www.ukbmd.org.uk/county/staffordshire/monumental_inscriptions/) at UKBMD
- [Staffordshire](https://www.cyndislist.com/uk/eng/counties/sts/), [Cemeteries](https://www.cyndislist.com/cemeteries/) and [Databases, searchable online](https://www.cyndislist.com/databases/) categories at Cyndi's list
- [Staffordshire Parish registers](http://www.dustydocs.com/county/34/staffordshire.html?country_id=1) and other records at DustyDocs
- [Monumental Inscriptions, Staffordshire](https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/results/r?_q=Monumental%20inscriptions%2C%20staffordshire) search of Other Archives at TNA's [Discovery](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/)
- Staffordshire County Council [Heritage and Arcives](https://www.staffordshire.gov.uk/Heritage-and-archives/homepage.aspx)

Specialist sites:

- Gravestone Photographic Resource: [Staffordshire locations](https://www.gravestonephotos.com/public/area.php?cemetery=3928)
- [Coverage page](https://www.deceasedonline.com/servlet/GSDOSearch) at Deceased Online
- [Staffordshire Cemetery Links](http://www.interment.net/uk/eng/staffordshire.htm) at Interment.net

Finding Published Sources:

- [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/) and [ArchiveGrid](https://researchworks.oclc.org/archivegrid/)
- [FamilySearch Books](https://www.familysearch.org/library/books/)
- [Google Books](https://books.google.com/) and [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/)
- [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/)
- [Hathi Trust](https://www.hathitrust.org/)
- [PERSI](https://search.findmypast.com/search-world-records/periodical-source-index) the Periodical Source Index at findmypast
- [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/)
- [Academia.edu](https://www.academia.edu/) warning: *nags users to subscribe*

Sites like JSTOR, Google Scholar, and Academia.edu may seem like a stretch, but by reading the bibliographies and citations in academic works, you can sometimes find real gems, and once you have a specific article or book title to look for, you can search for online copies in online digital libraries.

Also of interest:

- [Every Church of England graveyard to be digitally mapped](https://www.family-tree.co.uk/news/every-church-of-england-graveyard-to-be-digitally-mapped/)
   an article from Family Tree Magazine about Historic England's project for an online searchable database, described as ‘Google Maps for graves’, which links to a PDF download about the project: [About the Church of England National Burial Grounds Survey](https://03e2bd24-5ae4-4147-8ac5-31f897fe3108.filesusr.com/ugd/2feb15_0ac0ec68c6ce4e429df8dacf995ed18e.pdf) news via [@familytreemaguk on Twitter](https://twitter.com/familytreemaguk/status/1448929397944225801)

Resources:

- [How to Set up Google Alerts for Genealogy](https://lisalouisecooke.com/2014/07/13/set-google-alerts-for-genealogy/) by Lisa Louise Cook of *Genealogy Gems*
- [Genealogy Cheat Sheets](https://genealogybargains.com/free-genealogy-cheat-sheets/) by Thomas MacEntee, free to download from his site *Genealogy Bargains*. See: *Google Alerts for Genealogy & Family History*

---