# Seeking census records earlier than 1900 for Indiana ancestor named Delmain?

Tags: united-states, research-methods, census-records, indiana

I have hit a brickwall trying to research my GG Grandfather. The first census I can find him on is a 1900 census. It says he's from Indiana and I've even went through the ENTIRE census for that county on the next decade after his birth in 1861.

His name was Rosen Delmain (other variations I've seen are Roson Delmane and Rosan Delmayne). He was born around 1861. His exact birth year changed from census to census. His death certificate says he's from Logansport Indiana and I have several census' saying he is from Indiana. His parents are listed as unknown on his death certificate. Delmain is a very uncommon name and every Delmain I have found trace to him and his wife Mary Brown of Catawissa, MO. The first record I find of him is an 1883 marriage record to Mary Brown in MO. Then a 1900 census is the next record.

What other avenues can I look at to try and track him down?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Would you be able to [edit] your question to provide a link to the census record and/or mention your 2nd great grandfather's full name to help us try to help you to find more records for him.

Comment: There are some free Indiana databases mentioned at http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2519/19 which may be worth you looking at.

Comment: In one of the census records Rosen lists parents from Ohio, might look there. The first names of the sons (Oscar,Ivan,Elbert) are relatively unusual and may provide a clue as well( unless they can be connected to Mary Browns family line).

Comment: Welcome, Stephanie!  One caution: bear in mind that the census (except for 1900) usually does not give a year of birth -- it gives an age, from which Ancestry and other websites calculate an estimate of the year of birth.

Comment: Thank you! I always go a few years both ways just in case Jan Murphy. User 2448131-Those 3 listed are his Rosen and Mary's children. I saw the Ohio reference before and it has slipped my mind to start searching there too. I'll double check my efforts there! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Rosen's Obit is indexed in the [St Louis Post Dispatch](http://www.slpl.org/slpl/gateways/article240117800.asp?namefield3=1942&namefield1=Delman,%20Rosen) .

Answer (score 1):

Indiana has every-name census all the way back to 1850.

If you contact the Logansport-Cass County Public Library, they may have some information on the family in their files. Their address: 616 East Broadway, Logansport IN 46947. (574) 753-6383. library@logan.lib.IN.us  Their web site is logan.lib.IN.us

If you are on Ancestry.com or HeritageQuest Online you can search on the last name only plus the state and see what comes up. You will have to do a search on each variation of the last name. If you don't subscribe to either of those two services, Your local library probably does.

From those records you may be able to narrow down his birth month and year given his age and the date the census was taken.